# Transpose some columns in R

Tags: r, transpose, data-manipulation, spread

I have a data.frame df1 where I am tracking a monthly score:

```
Client_ID    |       Category    |        January       |       February 
  Stack                  A                  0.3                    0.2
 Overflow                B                  0.6                    0.7
```

I would like it to be like this:

```
Client_ID |         Category    |          Month        |        Score 
  Stack                  A                January                  0.3
 Overflow                B                January                  0.6   
  Stack                  A                February                 0.2
 Overflow                B                February                 0.7
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You tagged the question with `spread` but you'd need `melt` here (or `?reshape`).

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(df1, cols = -c("Client_ID", "Category"), names_to = "Month", values_to = "Score")`